# Force update with Branch Deep Link

Tags: branch.io

The two main use cases that Branch offers for deep-linking in the documentation are:

1. Deeplink directly into the app if the app is installed
2. Deeplink to the PlayStore/AppStore if the app is not installed and then forwarding the deeplink parameters

I'm curious if it is possible to always direct the user to the store in order to make sure they update the app to the latest version. Then, when the app is opened from the store the deep-link parameters are still available.

So the flow would be "Click on link" -> "Open play store/app store" -> "open app and handle deeplink"

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A Branchster here -

Yes you can do that either by appending your PlayStore Link as a [fallback](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/creating-a-deep-link#section-redirections) url or by customising your Advance Redirects in Configuration in your Branch Dashboard. Note that this updating the redirects might cause some issue with your default link [behaviour](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/default-link-behavior).